# Making Etsy OAuth2.0 call via Postman

Tags: postman, etsy

I am new to Etsy API development and I have been stuck on it for days. I have tried going through the doucmentation to find some resource so that I can make a simple API call (I plan to convert it to code but I want to get it running via Postman to see if it even works).

Please let me know if this is not the right platform and where should I post this? THANK YOU in advance.

Link to docs: https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference

I have tried adding headers but it still does not work. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Postman Call]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/essentials/oauth2

**steps:**

1. First create the app : https://www.etsy.com/developers/register
2. Now add call back URL by editing the app: https://www.etsy.com/developers/your-apps , go here and click the app name then scroll down and edit call back url :

[image]

and add below url: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback

If you cannot access the page to edit, look at the URL. If it reads "etsy.com/au/%20/developers/edit..." then delete "/%20" and retry.

3. now add below informations:

> ```
> Token Name : any name
> Grant Type: Authorization COde PKE
> Callback URL : https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback ( keep authroize using browser unchecked)
> auth url: https://www.etsy.com/oauth/connect
> Access Token URL: https://api.etsy.com/v3/public/oauth/token
> Client ID: Your appi KEYSTRING
> Client Secret: YOUR app secret
> Code Challenge Method: SHA256
> Code Verifier: leave blank
> Scope: scope eg: transactions_r (if using multiple scopes, separate each with a space, not with "%20" as the documentation says)
> State: superstate
> Client Authentication: Send Client Credentials in body
> ```

secret and keystring :

[image]

Final configuration:

[image]

Comment: I would give more than one upvote if I could. I was stuck on redirect URL. Thank you so much for the detailed post. Highly, Highly appreciate it.

Comment: Vital heads up. If you cannot access the page to edit, look at the URL. If it reads "https://www.etsy.com/au/%20/developers/edit..." then delete "/%20" and retry. You're welcome.

Comment: How has Etsy not hired you? This post reads far better than the documentation that corporation paid to have up! And you wrote it for free!

Comment: one more place to slip up, separate multiple scopes by spaces, not by "%20" as the documentation instructs. (Postman adds them automatically, and adding them manually throws an error)

Comment: man I love you. Etsy docs are a POS. You explained it so simple and straightforward that it took me only 5 minutes to do it. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

I am working on Etsy Authentication. I have created an app and tried to test the Authentication via Postman in the same above process but I was not able to Authenticate I was getting an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoOzx.png)

And I was unable to Edit the App  and also there is no option of **"Request Full Access"**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIvvK.png)

Help me with the issue as I was previously able to Edit the App and I have tested few APIs as well but now I am unable to do it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31245438)